# Is there a way to simplify multiple "greater than to"?

Tags: google-sheets, spreadsheet

My goal is to simplify this formula. The problem is, I have limited knowledge of Excel. So I rely on the If logical operators. And, as consequence, the if formula is quite long for just 1 column.

The overview:

[image]

The current formula:

```
=IF(G10<C$3,F10>D$3,  IF(G10<C$4,F10>D$4,  IF(G10<C$5,F10>D$5,  IF(G10<C$6,F10>D$6,  IF(G10>C$7,F10>D$7)))))
```

Comment: 1st thing is to remove the irrelevant tags. It's either Excel or Google Sheets. Looking at the screenshot it's the latter. 2nd, you left your current formula blank. Can you please edit your post?

Comment: Both Excel and Google Sheets have an `IFS(...)` function which is built for multiple possibilities (rather than the `IF(...)` that you mentioned)

Comment: @JvdV I have removed the excel tag. Thank you for the heads up. I also have added the formula back.

Comment: @SpencerBarnes ahh, I just checked how `ifs` work. My first impression was that `Ifs` means that all condition must be satisfied in order to return `true`, so I never tried to look it up. It turns out, it is not. `Ifs` can simplify the formula. Thank you.

Comment: How do you get these outcomes with that formula? It doesn't make sense. Please can you share a copy of your sheet, show us the desired results there?

Comment: @JvdV https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1xcSlDeM364y5IkB5vU1rchsBGr6ekbhzC_tguxjB8eY/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: @JvdV the intention of the formula is to calculate the engagement rate of an account in Instagram. How they are calculated is by averaging the interactions per posts (such as likes, comments). I will leave the spreadsheet for others to see on how "IFS" can shorten a "if" spaghetti.

Comment: @JvdV i see you went inactive, i think i found new formula based on your "MATCH" and "INDEX". I will set the spreadsheet to View mode only in 5 hours. Please write an answer explaining about the solution using `Index` and `Match`. It is really neat, I will mark it as answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just thought of another idea:

```
=INDEX(IF(F11:F<>"",LOOKUP(G11:G,C3:C7,D3:D7)<F11:F,""))
```

This will now spill-down results and will update these when you add more data.